# How are you supposed to format the output path in Webpack config for fonts?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, webpack

> The JS is bundling, the css is importing, but I am unable to change the font-family with this imported font. I believe it's an issue with the output config in my Webpack config but I've had no luck so far. All three formats of the font are valid, and I've used them in other projects. My "dist" folder is "public". In dev mode and after building the font does not apply.

[image: File Structure]

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: './[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: "./CovesTypeface",
          },
        },

      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

**index.css**

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'CovesBold';
    src: url("CovesTypeface/CovesBold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("CovesTypeface/CovesBold.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("CovesTypeface/CovesBold.otf") format("opentype");
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'CovesBold' !important;
}
```

**Structure after building**

[image]

Comment: What version of Webpack?

Comment: I just successfully loaded fonts in a local project with your Webpack config using Webpack `4.41.4`.

Comment: I'm using webpack 4.19.1. I'll update it later and then try to build again.. Were your directories the same as well? As in your webpack config was identical to mine?

Comment: @rossta I've updated to the latest version, still no luck. The font style doesn't apply. I can change it to Sans-Serif in my CSS just fine, but I can't seem to import that font after building.